# Pass a result of multiple grouping to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null).GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date}).OrderBy(d => d.Key).ToList()
```

How to pass the result of this code to View? Code is valid. What type must have View?

```
var Deliveries = Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null).GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date}).OrderBy(d => d.Key).ToList(); //It`s Ok.

List<IGrouping<{Crew:Crew, Date:DateTime}, Delivery>> Deliveries = Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null).GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date}).OrderBy(d => d.Key).ToList(); //It`s wrong.

List<IGrouping<{Crew, DateTime}, Delivery>> //This type is wrong too.
```

Or is exists any solution of this problem, without using anonymious types?

Sorry for my bad English, Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does `typeof(Deliveries).Name` get you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use an anonymous type in your GroupBy the result the type exists only virtually.
Either use

```
@model dynamic
```

or define a type for your result

```
public class GroupedDelivery{
    public Crew Crew {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date  {get;set;}
    public List<Delivery> Deliveries {get;set;}
}
```

Map the type in a Select after the GroupBy.

```
List<GroupedDelivery> Deliveries = Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null)
            .GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date})
            .Select(p => new GroupedDelivery{
                    Crew = p.Key.Crew,
                    Date = p.Key.Date,
                    Deliveries = p.Select(x => x).ToList()
                })
            .OrderBy(d => d.Crew).ThenBy(p => p.Date).ToList();
```